# How I can add subscript in main script so that subscript will copy in the folder created by mainscript?

Tags: shell, ksh

I have main.ksh script and  subscript.ksh. How I can add subscript in main script so that subscript will copy in the folder created by mainscript. Main script is running through Jenkins and Crete directories and I want subscript is also copy to these directories.but don't want subscript to run.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I am using korn shell script.

Comment: What do you mean by "add subscript in main script"? Can you show a [mre] that lets us see what you're trying to do and reproduce the problem you're experiencing when trying to do it?

Comment: Example my main script output is-
ExampleScript:A/B> ll

total 5

dr-x.

dr-x..

dr-x DATA

dr-x SQL


But I want output like this-
ExampleScript:A/B> ll

total 5

dr-x.

dr-x..

-rw-rw-r-- subscript.ksh

dr-x DATA

dr-x SQL